# Hint for showing that similar matrices have the same row rank and column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am aware that this proof must be in thousands of places online, but I would just like a hint please.

This problem is in Dummit and Foote before they introduce any matrix theory really; they only introduce matrices as representations of linear transformations.

My conjecture was that similar matrices have the same range. I made up a small $2 \times 2$ example and it worked.

Then I tried to actually prove it; assuming that $P^{-1}BP = A$, I tried to solve for $y$ in $Ax = By$. Multiplying on the left by $P$ gives $PAx = PBy$, so $BPx = PBy$. However, I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Similar matrices do **not** necessarily have the same range.  However: if $P^{-1}BP = A$, then $Px$ is in the range of $B$ if and only if $x$ is in the range of $A$.

Comment: For a concrete example: the similar matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
do not have the same range.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah okay thanks, now I know not to waste any more time with that. Did you just pick random matrices that happened to work, or did you have a way to come up with them? When I picked a random $P$ and $B$ (and figured out $A$) they happened to have the same range

Comment: any two invertible matrices will have the same range, and most matrices are invertible.  However, if you pick two random singular matrices, they are unlikely to have the same range.

Comment: as for my choice: diagonal matrices are almost always preferable if you can get away with using them

Answer (score 2):

Rank of a matrix is preserved under elementary row operations.

Now see what happens if your matrix is in row reduced echelon form and you multiply it by an invertible matrix.